# Trigger deployment_status from within another Github action

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

I have one action that sets the deployment status to success which in turn should trigger another action but that does not seem to work. Isn’t it possible to listen for deployment_status changes in one action that are triggered from within another action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, an action in a workflow run can’t trigger a new workflow run with the default GitHub token. Please refer to the official [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#about-workflow-events) for more details.

Creating personal access token as secrets instead is the workaround.